# Issuing reading JSON from POST

Tags: php, python, json, post

This using Python's requests to post JSON to my PHP server

```
url = 'http://www.domain.com/ex/S/A/R/PW'
payload = {'trackingNo': 'data'}  
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
datas = {'ids': [12, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print(r.text)
print(r.headers)
```

In PHP when I try var_dump I get null. But I do receive the echo.

```
var_dump($_POST[ids]);
var_dump($_POST);
echo "POSTED";
```

Reply from PHP

```
NULL
array(0) {
}
POSTED
```

Comment: `$_POST[ids]` should be `$_POST['ids']` for a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write in PHP:

```
var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Am i not suppose to be doing $_POST['ids'] ?

Answer (score 1):

Typo?
I guess you want to dump datas

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(datas), headers=headers)
```

instead of

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Comment: that was a typo! but still i tested it. Null still. @Alexandr Kapustin  solution worked >.<

Comment: If that typo was in your script too and not only in your post, this would have been the next error as you were not sending any data thanks to the typo :)